# Mongodb version 3+: how to insert new document only if it doesn't exist and get the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have tried dozens of solutions, and none of these worked and most of them are deprecated.

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
    _id: 5d99ef3285c93711828cd15d
    code: 1234
    name: "Foo"
    surname: "Bar"
    address: "That street"
    phone: 1234567
```

I would like to insert new document only if there isn't any document with the same `code`.

My last try was this:

```
const result = await db.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate(
    { code: user.code },
    {
        $setOnInsert: user,
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
    }
);
```

but I get **E11000 duplicate key error collection**...

`updateOne()` returns the same error; `update()` is deprecated...

So, how to add only new document and get the result (true if document has been added or false if it already exists)?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the full duplicate key error message? What indexes do you have on the `users` collection?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge is,

with $set and $setOnInsert, we can **not** update/insert the same field.

i.e. **$set and $setOnInsert should be mutually exclusive.**

It works if the document is being updated, but throws an exception if document is being inserted.

In case of update, $setOnInsert will be ignored.

In case of insertion, both will be executed.

I think the solution would be,

use **returnNewDocument**  and have one field in the schema `isUpdated` defaults to false.

> Note:
>
> make sure whenever you use "insert" operation on the collection, you don't add `isUpdated` which will be set to false then or set it to false.

form a query like

```
db.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate(
    { code: user.code },
    {
        $set: user,          // which has user.isUpdated set to true
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        returnNewDocument: false, // (by default it is false only)
    }
);
```

With this logic,

So let's go step by step,

1. If the document `doc1` is not present, it will be inserted, and mongo will return the response `null`. You will know, it is **Inserted**.
2. If the document doc2 is present(considering this logic is not applied on the previously inserted document `doc2` before and `isUpdated` field is not present in doc2), it will execute $set so in returned cursor, this field not present i.e. `undefined`, so you know from this, it is **updated**.
3. let's say we fire the same query for `doc1` again (which is present and we have applied our new logic), then there are two cases

   a.  it will be updated and in the cursor, we have `isUpdated` equal to false.

   b.  it will be updated and in the cursor, we have `isUpdated` equal to true.

   In both case you know it is **Updated**

I think this approach should solve your problem.

Please share if this helps you, or you find any other solution.

**UPDATE**

**ACTUALLY**

**You dont even need another field `isUpdated`, without this fiels this should work with the same logic.**

**i.e. If cursor is null then its inserted, if not null then its updated.**

Comment: On existing item it always returns something like this: `{ lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: true },
  value:
   { _id: 5d9c3aae2ac8193c4b846b87, ...`. On non-existing item it returns: `{ lastErrorObject:
   { n: 1,
     updatedExisting: false,
     upserted: 5d9c3aae2ac8193c4b846b87 },
  value: null, ...`. Is it right?

Comment: Sometimes it gives this error: `MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'...`. What is wrong?

Comment: that error is bcs your user object in "$set: user",  has user._id property which could be different, and you are matching with user.code. Hence you delete user._id before you send it for an update.

Comment: ya, for your first comment, you should look for ".value" property.

Comment: Just remove "_id" property from the user object.. that should work.

Comment: I have no `_id` property in my user object. It is automatically created when I save it to mongodb.

Comment: Do you have an "id"  property (without the underscore) in your object? Basically, when you update/insert _id/id is being inserted/updated by you, and that is not acceptable in mongo. So remove both "_id" and "id" from your "user" object.

Comment: No, I haven't `id` property. About `_id`, it is generated by mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You can still run a query like this;

```
document = db.collection('users').findOne({code:userCode});
if(document == null){
     //document  doesn't exists so you can use insertOne
}
else{
// document exists, sou you can update
}
```

it won't be efficient but it'll do the work.

Comment: Seems to be a dirty way to do it... Is so weird to add item only if it doesn't exist?

Comment: well the error you get is most likely due to you set the "code" field as unique index. But, upsert should've worked that out. Besides, I have a question, the dictionary/document you are trying to push; does it contain "_id" key?

Comment: `code` is not unique index. The document I want to insert doesn't contain `_id` key. It gets it after it is stored in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the request with a try/catch block to catch the Error. Then return false when this exception occured.

Comment: Why it gives error? Doesn't `$setOnInsert` add item to collection only if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe your filtering is incorect? Can you tell what column is producing the Error? May it be that another column than `code` needs to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

You could use findOne to see if a user with that code exists first

```
const result = await db.collection('users')
    .findOne({ code: user.code });

if( result ){ 
  return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User already exists' }] });
}
//create 
user = new User({
     code = code, 
     name = name, 
     foo = foo
)}
//save
user.save();   
res.json(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   db.collection("users").findOne({ code: user.code }, (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        return res.send(false);
      } else {
        // a document
        var user = new User({
          code: code,
          name: "Foo",
          surname: "Bar",
          address: "That street",
          phone: 1234568
        });

        // save model to database
        user.save(function(err, book) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          return res.send(true);
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Users.findOneAndUpdate({code:user.code}, {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, function(error, result) { if (error) return; // do something with the document }).
```

I think it would work. Let us know if you have any questions.